# External display briefly turns off under load

Tags: fedora, display

I am currently running Fedora 29 (but the same thing was happening under Ubuntu 18.10) on Lenovo X1 Carbon 6th gen.

When I am putting my computer under a slight load external display turns off for couple seconds and then it turns on again. Here is what comes in `journalctl` when that happens:

```
Mar 11 21:55:16 failbowl kernel: usb 1-3: USB disconnect, device number 124
Mar 11 21:55:16 failbowl kernel: usb 1-3.1: USB disconnect, device number 125
Mar 11 21:55:16 failbowl kernel: usb 1-3.1.2: USB disconnect, device number 126
Mar 11 21:55:16 failbowl kernel: usb 1-3.1.3: USB disconnect, device number 127
Mar 11 21:55:16 failbowl kernel: usb 1-3.1.3.1: USB disconnect, device number 6
Mar 11 21:55:16 failbowl snapd[2969]: udevmon.go:190: udev monitor observed remove event for unknown device "/sys/usbmisc"
Mar 11 21:55:16 failbowl kernel: CPU6: Core temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 8712)
Mar 11 21:55:16 failbowl kernel: CPU2: Core temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 8712)
Mar 11 21:55:16 failbowl kernel: CPU1: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 23696)
Mar 11 21:55:16 failbowl kernel: CPU3: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 23696)
Mar 11 21:55:16 failbowl kernel: CPU4: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 23696)
Mar 11 21:55:16 failbowl kernel: CPU0: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 23696)
Mar 11 21:55:16 failbowl kernel: CPU5: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 23696)
Mar 11 21:55:16 failbowl kernel: CPU7: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 23696)
Mar 11 21:55:16 failbowl kernel: CPU2: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 23696)
Mar 11 21:55:16 failbowl kernel: CPU6: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 23696)
Mar 11 21:55:16 failbowl kernel: CPU2: Core temperature/speed normal
Mar 11 21:55:16 failbowl kernel: CPU6: Core temperature/speed normal
Mar 11 21:55:16 failbowl kernel: CPU1: Package temperature/speed normal
Mar 11 21:55:16 failbowl kernel: CPU5: Package temperature/speed normal
Mar 11 21:55:16 failbowl kernel: CPU0: Package temperature/speed normal
Mar 11 21:55:16 failbowl kernel: CPU3: Package temperature/speed normal
Mar 11 21:55:16 failbowl kernel: CPU4: Package temperature/speed normal
Mar 11 21:55:16 failbowl kernel: CPU7: Package temperature/speed normal
Mar 11 21:55:16 failbowl kernel: CPU6: Package temperature/speed normal
Mar 11 21:55:16 failbowl kernel: CPU2: Package temperature/speed normal
```

Temperature is never spiking during that though and stayed under 50C in this particular case. This is not happening when external display is off.

Any ideas what might be wrong or where else can I look to figure out what is going on?

Comment: Did you get to the bottom of this? I'm having the same issue with an X1 Carbon gen 7 and various external displays connected over usb-c. If I connect a display via HDMI then it works well.